# How to join records by date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to match scrap records in one table with records indicating the material that was running at the same time on a machine. I have a table with the scrap counts and a table with records showing whenever the material changed on a machine.

I have a working query of which I will include a simplified version below, but it is very slow when applied to a large data set. I would like to try one of Oracle's analytical functions to make it faster, but I can't figure out how. I tried FIRST_VALUE, and ROW_NUMBER in a few different forms, but I couldn't get them right. Looking for any suggestions.

Please let me know if you would like more details.

Following are simplified versions of the tables:

**Scrap readings table (~41m rows)**

- Machine
- ScrapReasonCode
- ScrapQuantity
- ReportTime

**Material numbers (~3m rows)**

- Machine
- MaterialNumber
- MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP

```
  SELECT Scrap.Machine,
       Scrap.MaterialNumber,
       Scrap.ScrapReasonCode,
       Scrap.ScrapQuantity,
       Scrap.ReportTime
  FROM Scrap, Materials
  WHERE Scrap.Machine = Materials.Machine
       AND Materials.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP =
               (SELECT MAX (M2.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP)
                FROM Materials M2
                WHERE M2.Materials.Machine = Scrap.Machine
                       AND M2.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP <= Scrap.ReportTime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. You can use the `FIRST_VALUE` window function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       s.Machine,
       s.MaterialNumber,
       s.ScrapReasonCode,
       s.ScrapQuantity,
       s.ReportTime,
       FIRST_VALUE(m.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY s.Machine ORDER BY m.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP DESC)
  --or you can use the `MAX` window function too. 
  --MAX(m.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY s.Machine)
FROM Scrap s
JOIN Materials m
WHERE s.Machine = m.Machine AND m.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP <= s.ReportTime
```

Comment: I need the most recent MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP before the ReportTime of the scrap record.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your requirements but I believe the following query should work in terms of implementing using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Scrap.Machine ORDER BY Materials.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP DESC) AS RNO 
       Scrap.MaterialNumber,
       Scrap.ScrapReasonCode,
       Scrap.ScrapQuantity,
       Scrap.ReportTime
  FROM Scrap, Materials
 WHERE     Scrap.Machine = Materials.Machine
       AND Materials.MEASUREMENT_TIMESTAMP <= Scrap.ReportTime
) q 
WHERE q.RNO = 1
```

Edit: if you need the measurement timestamp before (rather than on-or-before) the Scrap ReportTime, you could just change the `<=` sign to a `<` sign in the query above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will continue to study, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this method work. Probably just a deficiency on my part. :)